# Does elementary os support nvidia geforce GT 525M

Tags: updates, display, nvidia, elementary-project, release-jolnir

I am currently using a linux distro not supported by my legacy nvidia driver and so i will like to saitch to one that is supported i would like to know if elementary supports legacy nvidia graphics.

And what has been the experience for nvidia users?

Answer (score 0):

elementaryOS is Ubuntu 20.04 based OS, which could broaden your search for solutions.

Looking at Hardware for Linux page it should work:
https://linux-hardware.org/index.php?id=pci:10de-0df5-1028-04b6

Comment: Thanks for the reply elementary os is not listed on the list and the distro listed seems to have been tested and confirmed compatible with the drivers